# How to read values from dynamic child components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multiple rows which are generated based on a multi select. Each row will again have multiple input elements. My requirement is as below.

- For each option selected in the multi select, get the input values from the row that was created when that option is selected.

To achieve this I had two components one parent Multi Select component and a child row component with different input fields. I am confused as to where should I store the state of the child row components.

If I store it in the row itself how do I update the parent state as each input field is a property of the selected option.

If I store the state in the parent how do I know which child row is getting updated for the input fields.

I looked at refs in react but unable to get a hold on how to use them if the child row count is dynamic.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0xm8m2v1mn) is a sample react code that replicates the above scenario.

Comment: You have to use an array in the component state and have to manipulate it as you want. You can use `axios` to make it easy
https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: As per my knowledge axios is for making API calls. I am not doing any API calls. I already have the required data that I need. I am using array but how do I find the index of the row so that I can update the array in the parent component.

Comment: Actually sorry my mistake. use `lodash` https://lodash.com/

Comment: I can copy the objects with lodash but how do I manage the parent child relation. Are there any other methods in lodash that would help me solve this problem. If so would you please share link or an example of how you do it.

Comment: You have to use a dimensional array.`_.findIndex`,`_.filter` those can be used when working with arrays